# How do I create specific text format in a text file?

Tags: c#, .net

The format I need to create/write to the text file is this:

```
int[,] map = new int[,] 
{
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,},
};
```

This is the code I'm using now to create it:

```
            int count = 0;
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\test\test.txt");
            w.Write("{");
            for (int k = 0; k < ret.GetLength(0); k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < ret.GetLength(1); l++)
                {
                    var val = ret[k, l];
                    w.Write("," + val);
                    count++;
                    if (count == 8)
                    {
                        w.Write("},");
                        w.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                        w.Write("{");
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            w.Close();
        }
```

What I get so far in the end in the text file is this:

```
{,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1},
{,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0},
{,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
{,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
{
```

It's almost fine but how do I rid/remove the last `{` ?
The result should be for now:

```
{,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1},
{,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
{,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0},
{,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
{,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
```

I and then later to add the rest the `};` in the end and the rest I will add later.
But first only this part how to remove the last `{`

Comment: The way that the line information is being written is a bit chaotic to say the least, try doing it in a more structured and logical / maintainable way, e.g. w.Write("{"); before you even enter the loop and see if there is indeed any information to write is your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be much simpler:

```
using( StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\test\test.txt"))
{
    for (int k = 0; k < ret.GetLength(0); k++)
    {
        w.Write("{");
        for (int l = 0; l < ret.GetLength(1); l++)
        {
            var val = ret[k, l];
            w.Write(val + ",");
        }
        w.WriteLine("},");
    }
}
```

Here's [Ideone sample](http://ideone.com/kCKk2G)

Also, Please use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx). Don't manually code the Stream/StreamWriter yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have reached the end of your 2-D array before adding the extra brace bracket, like so:

```
if (count == 8)
                {
                    w.Write("},");
                    w.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                    if(k != ret.GetLength(0) - 1 && l != ret.GetLength(1)-1)
                    {
                     w.Write("{");
                    }
                    count = 0;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code like this:

```
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\test\test.txt");
for (int k = 0; k < ret.GetLength(0); k++)
{
    w.Write("{");
    for (int l = 0; l < ret.GetLength(1); l++)
    {
        w.Write(ret[k,l]);
        if(l < ret.GetLength(1)-1)
            w.Write(",");
    }
    w.WriteLine("},");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// First opening bracket
w.WriteLine("{");

for (int i = 0; i < ret.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    // each line starts with an opening bracket
    w.Write("{");
    for (int j = 0; j < ret.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        w.Write( = ret[i, j];
        if (j<7) // all commas but for the last
            w.Write(","}
    }
    w.WriteLine("},") // at the end of the line, close and comma
}
w.WriteLine("}") // close top bracket
w.Close();
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the pile of answers a bit of LINQ fun.

```
var rows = map.Cast<int>().Select((m, i) => new { m, i }).ToLookup(o => o.i / map.GetLength(0), o => o.m);
var text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows.Select(r => string.Format("{{ {0} }},", string.Join(",", r))));

File.WriteAllText("foo.txt", text);
```